# Adding data into database table through GUI of Java.

Tags: java, mysql, database, db2

I created a simple table in **IBM DB2** named **"NAMES"** with a single column "FullName" with a ***datatype of VARCHAR(20)***. I've also created a GUI with a JTextfield and JButton to ***add data into the table through GUI***. When the button is clicked, the text in the textfield will be inserted into the table NAMES. But there's an ***error*** when I click the button. 
Here is the java code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class FirstClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private Connection connection;
    private JTextField fieldTF;
    private JButton addB;

    public FirstClass()  throws SQLException , ClassNotFoundException
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        fieldTF = new JTextField(20);
        addB = new JButton("Add");

        Container cont = this.getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        cont.add(fieldTF);
        cont.add(addB);

        setConnection();

        addB.addActionListener(this);

        pack();
        validate();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setConnection() throws SQLException , ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/COLINN","Colinn","ezioauditore");
        System.out.print("Connected Succesfully");
    }

    public void write(String name)  throws SQLException , ClassNotFoundException
    {
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        String query = null;
        query = "INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES (?)";

        statement.setString(1,name);
        statement.executeUpdate();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
            try
            {
                write(fieldTF.getText());           
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }   
    }

    public static void main(String args[])  throws SQLException , ClassNotFoundException
    {
        new FirstClass();
    }

}
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FirstYearProject.FirstClass.write(FirstClass.java:49)
    at FirstYearProject.FirstClass.actionPerformed(FirstClass.java:58)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've already imported External Jars from DB2 to establish connection with Java. I think there's a problem with the query or problem in executing it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem here:

```
    PreparedStatement statement = null; // **** set to null here
    String query = null;
    query = "INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES (?)";

    statement.setString(1,name); // **** use it here!
```

Where does `statement` become non-null before you use it?

You need to key in on line 49 and 58 of the FirstClass.java class as per the exception stacktrace message, `FirstClass.java:49`.

Also, you will want to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (`NullPointerException`). You should **critically** read your exception's stacktrace to **find the line** of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

So here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FirstYearProject.FirstClass.write(FirstClass.java:49)
    at FirstYearProject.FirstClass.actionPerformed(FirstClass.java:58)
```

The stacktrace tells you to carefully inspect lines 49 and 58.

---

Note, you need to create a PreparedStatement  object **before** you try to use it. First you'd create a Connection, and then you'd use that Connection to create the PreparedStatement  via Connection's `preparedStatement(...)` method. This is all well described in the [Java JDBC Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). Pay particular attention to the [PreparedStatement subsection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: So that block of code is really the function in writing into the database? And I just need to find the errors that stacktrace tells me from the specific line of code.

Comment: @ZeroCool: You need to create a PreparedStatement  object **before** you try to use it. First you'd create a Connection, and then you'd use that Connection to create the PreparedStatement  via Connection's `preparedStatement(...)` method. This is all well described in the [Java JDBC Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). Pay particular attention to the [PreparedStatement subsection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).